# H-Bridge freewheeling

Tags: power-electronics

I am building an H-bridge motor control for DC motor . I am using  ["SQD40N06-14L_GE3 "](http://www.vishay.com/docs/67002/sqd40n06-14l.pdf) N_channel MOSFET. Did i have to add a rectifier in parallel with the mosfet (the mosfet already have one integrated).Thanks

Comment: What current will the DC motor draw?

Comment: The DC motor will draw up to 20A.

Answer (score 1):

The internal parasitic body diode of the MOSFET can be used, but will not be optimal since it's a byproduct of MOSFET construction (too slow, not soft recovery, inefficient). The body diode will be insufficient for some projects. A very few MOSFETs try to optimize the body diode a little bit to reduce overall component costs in a project, but >99% do not.

I always use external diodes.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that some mosfets, especially power switching devices, have an antiparallel diode on a separate chip in the same package, specifically to give a well-characterised source-drain diode. I've seen this in power modules, at the very least.

Comment: I've seen this in a few smaller MOSFETs too where a schottky diode is incorporated (I don't think it's a body diode made to be a schottky, or if that is even possible , but I don't really know)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to make a FET with a schottky body diode. Many FET symbols draw the body diode as a zener, however, which may be what you're thinking of? They have similar symbols.

Comment: I'm just saying I don't know whether it's a discrete schottky diode (body diode is still there just no one cares about it anymore since the schottky is also there) or they somehow turned the body diode into a schottky. I tend to assume the former. But the MOSFETs that do this are not discrete about it; It's a very clear selling point of the device so it's definitely there.

Comment: Even if using the body is not ideal, why does the recovery matter? The diode turns on during the dead-time but never really has to turn off fast, because the next thing is typically the channel turning on, too, so the diode will be gracefully shunted by the FET channel.

Comment: @tobalt I'm a bit fuzzy on the details but the recovery either increases heating in the MOSFET and/or causes other spikes or ringing or something like that. More literature about it can be found regarding SMPS than H-bridges. This is the most focused document but might not be the easiest to understand since it goes into it so much: https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/application_note_en_20180901_AKX00076.pdf?did=63591

Comment: Indeed, RR occurs when the other FET turns on after the dead time. Didn't think about that. It is essentially a short shootthrough condition and indeed very bad.